# "someone’s" vs. "someone else’s"-- any difference?

Tags: word-usage

I am going through the meaning of "errand": The Oxford Languages defines it as:

> a short journey undertaken in order to deliver or collect something, especially on someone else’s behalf

I write it in my notes as:

> a short journey undertaken in order to deliver or collect something, especially on someone’s behalf

Is there any difference between "someone’s" and "someone else’s"? Do I need to change my notes to “someone else’s”?

Comment: Yes, there's a difference, but in that context, there isn't because "on...behalf" means as representative or proxy for another (i.e., someone else), so there's no meaningful difference between saying "on someone's behalf" and saying "on someone else's behalf." That said, I don't agree that the word "errand" expresses anything at all about it being on someone's/someone else's behalf. If I say, "I spent the morning running errands," there's no built-in implication, suggestion, or hint that those errands were for someone else.

Comment: @Benjamin Harman, thanks for clarification on “on behalf”. you also mentioned that any task is errand, not necessarily on behalf of some one. I agree. but that is from Oxford languages dictionary and they used “especially on someone else’s”. Do we need to write to Oxford to remove “especially on some one else’s” ?

Comment: an errand is not a journey. An errand is to go and get something.

Comment: @Lambie, agree with you, but the definition was given by Oxford Languages. Any channel to feedback them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking "someone" rather than "someone else" *could* include yourself and it is quite permissible to say "I'm collecting this on my own behalf" so, yes, there is a difference.

Most people would interpret the phrase without the word "else" in it as meaning someone other than yourself but, strictly, you should include it: "someone  else's" also sounds more colloquial. I would include the "else".

Comment: coming to the overall meaning of errand, does “especially on someone else’s behalf” is required? what are tour thoughts on this oxford entry?

Comment: @Rachayita - Oxford's use of *someone else's* behalf is interesting.  The definition is clear and would be understood the way BoldBen says.  I do not think of errands as things I do for someone else.  I would use errand to mean *send mail, buy groceries, renew my driver's license, etc.*  Maybe I just use it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference.

Someone = Anybody (including me)

Someone Else = Anybody but not me

Comment: okay. in the context of above sentence if you apply this rule then someone and someone else both point to the same meaning, i think

Comment: Different meanings, as everyone has pointed out.  It's Sunday morning, Timmy and Susie are playing Mario Cart, Dad is cooking breakfast, and Mom is in the bathtub.  The doorbell rings.  Mom says, "Someone get the door."  Nothing happens; no one moves.  Everyone thinks Mom will get the door like she always does.  But if Mom says, "Someone else get the door," she means she will not be getting the door but someone will need to.

Comment: noted the subtle difference